# Two handlers process the data in the same way and get different output

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

**UPDATE 2**
This seems to be a problem with the PHP port of Deam Edwards JS Packer. I am using the [version on github](https://github.com/tholu/php-packer) last updated in 2008. This is the only verion I could find and it seems a bit tempremental with some things working or not working. For example:

```
console.log("Return character: " + ("\n".charCodeAt(0)));
```

Without packing it correctly shows 10. With packing, it shows 124 or 115 in 2 separate places for no apparent reason.

I'll leave this question up unless there is a big push to delete it.

**Original Post**

I have a piece of code that is calling an API to get an array of teams each with an array of members and processing the pulled back data.

I iterate through each team and combine the members into a string so I can use it in a text area later, and I want one member per line. Here is the processing:

```
$scope.teams[i].memberList = ($scope.teams[i].members).join("\n");
console.log("Got text area stuff");
console.log($scope.teams[i].members);
console.log($scope.teams[i].memberList);
```

This code works elsewhere, but when I call here I get the following in the console:

[image: Console output]

My deductive logic based on the console output is this:

- You can clearly see that `$scope.teams[i].members` is an array of 3 strings.
- One can assume that `array.join("\n")` will add carriage returns
- where did the 's' come from in the text output?

Here is the modified object from the results:

[image: More detail]

What am I missing?

If I join with `", "` I get the string I'd expect: `aaa, bbb, ccc`

**UPDATE:**

I wrote a simple joiny function to see if I could override what I thought was an override:

```
Array.prototype.myJoin = function(str) {
    var ret = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(i > 0) {
            ret = ret + str;
        }
        ret = ret + this[i];
    }
    return ret;
};
```

It still returns exactly the same thing as before, writing this in the same place above:

```
console.log(["a","b","c"].myJoin("\n"));
```

The console shows `asbsc`

Comment: Has your `Array.prototype.join` method been overwritten with something else?

Comment: you can test with any array in console, which for me gives `"aaa↵bbb↵ccc"`, check if your `join()` works correctly

Comment: Works [fine](http://jsbin.com/luqiwuvore/edit?js,console) for me, so yeah, maybe your `join` is overwritten, or something in your environment is wrong. Check `console.log(Array.prototype.join)`

Comment: I've checked every bit of code I have and I can't find `.join` being redefined. Trying the console directly with`["aaa","bbb","ccc"].join("\n")` does as expected.

Comment: What happens if you just do directly `console.log(["a","b","c"].join("\n"))` in your application, at the point in the code that you have shown?

Comment: After checking `console.log(Array.prototype.join)` was native code, I tried the note above and got `asbsc`. I then wrote a myJoin and used that, and got the same. Files are returning UTF-8 so it's not an encoding thing???

Comment: Any escaped character seems to do it: \n \r \t ???

Comment: All of a sudden it started working. I added `console.log("\n".charCodeAt(0));` in the same place and it comes back as 115... not 10. I put it in another place I was having problems with join and carriage returns and it comes back with 124???

Comment: Maybe: I was running the code through the PHP port of the Dean Edwards JSPacker script. I did notice it was having some problems with packing some regex expressions that had a complex escape sequence. When I run native JS without the packing I get 10 as the character code for a carriage return.